# typo3 how to configure realurl for dd_googlesitemap

Tags: typo3, sitemap, realurl, tx-news

I use realurl in combination with [dd_googlesitemap](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/dd_googlesitemap) and [news](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/news) extension. The generated news url looks like `/company/news/news-detail/detail/News/8/2016/newstitle/` and that's the right format.

But in _dd_googlesitemap_ the url is `/company/news/news-detail///newstitle/`. The month and year parameters where stripped. How could I configure the sitemap news markup in the `realurl_conf.php`? If you need some code snippets, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is indeed missing in the version *4.3.0*. However I have fixed it now and it will be integrated in the upcoming version *5.0.0*.

As there is no release date yet, there are 2 ways to get it:

1. Use the master version https://github.com/TYPO3-extensions/news
2. Override the hook with the new one which you can find at https://github.com/TYPO3-extensions/news/blob/master/Classes/Hooks/TxNewsSitemapGenerator.php

Additionally a bit of configuration is required:

```
    tx_ddgooglesitemap.tx_news {
      hrDate = 1
      hrDate {
        day = j
        month = n
        year = Y
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I only needed to do step 2 and the configuration and now it works. They should fix this bug soon or add some notes to the manual.

Comment: I am the author of the extension and I will do both :)